# Require help on a logical issue

Tags: java, for-loop, logic, if-statement

I'm not sure how I can make the final '**else if**' statement work correctly.

The code in question is currently hashed out and is located at the very bottom of the program. Reading the other '**else if**' statements above will probably give you better insight into my thought process.

**i.e** I'm not sure how I can make the final '**else if**' work since it doesn't have a defined maximum value.

```
    else if((gross_income >= 80001) && (gross_income <= 180000))
                {
                        gross_income = gross_income - 80000;
                        tax_payable = tax_payable + 17547;

                        for(i = 1; i <= gross_income; i++)
                        {
                                tax_payable = tax_payable + 0.37;
                        }

                        System.out.print("\n\n");
                        System.out.print("YOU MUST PAY $" + df.format(tax_payable) + " IN TAX!");
                        System.out.print("\n\n");
                }
//              else if(gross_income >= 180001)
//              {
//                      gross_income = gross_income - 180000;
//                      tax_payable = tax_payable + 54547;
//
//                      for(?????)
//                      {
//                              tax_payable = tax_payable + 0.45;
//                      }
//
//                      System.out.print("\n\n");
//                      System.out.print("YOU MUST PAY $" + df.format(tax_payable) + " IN TAX!");
//                      System.out.print("\n\n");
//              }
        }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you getting? What do you want to get?

Comment: *"REQUIRE HELP ON A LOGICAL ISSUE"*  First fix that caps. key.  There is no need to SHOUT at us.

Comment: For example, if I enter $200,000 I would like it to calculate the amount of tax payable. But because the final one doesn't have a pre defined maximum value I can't loop it around like I did with my previous ones.

Comment: `for(i = 1; i <= gross_income; i++) tax_payable = tax_payable + 0.37;` is most definatly the most awesome percentage calucaltion ( tax = x * 0.37 did not suit you? ) I have seen in a long time

Comment: Why do you need else if? Why not just use an else if there is no defined max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, because I loved your tax calculation so much:

do it this way - always try to prevent double code (eg the calculation is done once, the only thing changing is the tax-percentage):

```
double perc = 0.0;

if( gross_income < 80001 ) 
{
    perc = 0.16; // dont know american tax limits, so lets pretend 0.16
}
else if( gross_income >= 80001 && gross_income < 180001 )
{
    perc = 0.37;
}
else
{
    perc = 0.45;
}
tax_payable = gross_income * perc;

System.out.print("\n\n");... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, Najzero. If I need to do something similar in the future I'll be sure to use the code you've shown me.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct, as the marginal tax rate is usually applied only to the amount above the minimum of the Bracket. So the effective tax rate is always less than the marginla rate. However, I do agree there is no need to go through this ugly loop.